# How do I add the length of strings together?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a program that takes the length of my first, middle, and last name, individually, and then adds the total amount of letters up in the end. My answer keeps on being 666 instead of 18. Here is the code I have written.

```
puts 'What is your first name?'

firstName = gets.chomp
realFirstName = firstName.length.to_i

puts 'What is your middle name?'

middleName = gets.chomp
realMiddleName = middleName.length.to_i

puts 'What is your last name?'

lastName = gets.chomp
realLastName = lastName.length.to_i

puts 'Did you know there are ' + realFirstName.to_s + realMiddleName.to_s + realLastName.to_s + ' letters in your name?'
```

Just wondering where I went wrong.

Comment: The `to_i`s after the `length` calls are redundant -- their already `Fixnum`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're converting the integers back into strings on the last line, you're concatenating *strings*, not adding numbers. What you're doing is:

```
"6" + "6" + "6"  #=> "666"
```

Just don't call `to_s` on the numbers and add them up prior instead:

```
letters_count = realFirstName + realMiddleName + realLastName
puts "Did you know there are #{letters_count} letters in your name?"
```

I've also used *string interpolation* to make it a bit easier to read.

There's also no need to call `to_i` after calling `length`, since `length` already returns an integer.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! When I did that I got the following error: characters.rb:11:in `+': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)
 from characters.rb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: Here is line 10 and 11:lettersCount = realFirstName + realMiddleName + realLastName
puts 'Did you know there are ' + lettersCount + ' letters in your name?'

Comment: That won't work. You either need to call `to_s` on `lettersCount` on line 11 or use string interpolation (which implicitly calls `to_s`) as in my answer. You can't concatenate a string and number in Ruby.

Comment: Ahhh ok I get it now. That makes a lot more sense. Thanks for the patience Andrew!

Answer (score 1):

#### What Went Wrong

You aren't adding anything. The + operator is actually a method that behaves differently on strings and numbers. In your case, realFirstName.to_s and friends are turning Fixnum objects (which can be added) into String objects (which use the same operator for concatenation). There's nothing wrong with using #to_i and #to_s, but if you make the conversion at the wrong time, you can get into trouble.

#### What Will Go Right

String#length will return the number of characters in a string. Since it returns Fixnum, and the Fixnum#+ method performs addition, it will behave the way you expect if you call it before you convert to a string. Both of these examples should be equivalent.

```
# Adding the Fixnum objects.
letter_count = realFirstName + realMiddleName + realLastName
puts "Did you know there are #{letter_count} letters in your name?"

# Adding the String lengths.
letter_count = realFirstName.length + realMiddleName.length + realLastName.length
puts "Did you know there are #{letter_count} letters in your name?"
```

In this example, we add up all the Fixnum objects, then interpolate the result into our string. Note that #{} does an implicit #to_s for you, so you don't have to do it yourself.

#### An Advanced Ruby Idiom for the Adventurous

Whether or not this is clearer (it probably isn't), you'll probably run across a lot more examples like the following in real-world Ruby code.

```
puts "Did you know there are %d letters in your name?" %
  [firstName, middleName, lastName].map(&:length).reduce(:+)
```

Ruby can be a brain-bender, but it's fun!

Comment: Careful, the "`real`" prefixed variables are where they stored the length, but you're using them as if they're the original strings.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Thanks; fixed. I was enjoying the explanation so much I didn't pay enough attention to the OPs naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write .to_s after each term.

Comment: This isn't enough, simply removing the calls to `to_s` results in a TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

That's because that plus sign in that context is for concatenation. Like you do `"something" + "else"`.

you can solve it easly by creating a different variable

```
size = realFirstName + realMiddleName+ realLastName

puts 'Did you know there are ' + size.to_s + ' letters in your name?'
```

Or doing interpolation

```
puts "Did you know there are #{realFirstName + realMiddleName + realLastName}  letters in your name?"
```

Notice that you need double quote for using interpolation, and no need to call `to_s`

In the first case you can also use interpolation.

To understand why this happens with the plus sign:
Plus sign in Ruby is an operator that actually calls a method, and in your case it's beeing called in a string. if you did `1 + "asd` it would give a error since + method expects an Fixnum as parameter. The + method in string expects a string.

Comment: `+` is an operator that calls a method, but is not a method itself. Also, instead of telling us to ignore part of your answer, why not just remove it?

Comment: Good to know, but what's the difference? Well, I think it's important to know that in other languages this happens.

Comment: The difference is how they're parsed. Most operators call methods, but not all do, and this makes them essentially just syntactic sugar. `1.+(2)` is a method call, while `1 + 2` uses an operator that makes the same method call as before. But this question is about Ruby, not what unspecified other languages do.

Comment: Ok, I get the difference since you don't do "something".+ "else". But what I wanted to say is that each Class defines what to do when a plus sign is used.

Comment: I will remove that part just to make you happier @AndrewMarshall